# Counting the elements of an array and creating another array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `y`. I want to create another array `x` which is based on the length of `y`. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
import numpy as np

y=np.array([60.        , 57.71689783, 43.92696073, 41.27856221, 52.87672123,
        46.75800742, 40.36532134, 42.10047899, 44.65755342, 52.69407306,
        48.49316507, 53.78, 55.0        ])

x=np.array([len(y)])
```

The current output is

```
array([13])
```

The expected output is

```
array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13])
```

Comment: `numpy.arange(1,len(y)+1)` gives that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... using arange

```
x=np.arange(1,len(y)+1)
```